# Custom Configuration Section - Multiple Collections

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config, system.configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Create a Configuration Section That Contains a Collection of Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958054/how-to-create-a-configuration-section-that-contains-a-collection-of-collections)

I would like to create something like this custom section in a web.config

```
<MyCustomSection>
     <Collection name="test">
        <item name="foo" />
        <item name="bar">
     </Collection>
     <Collection name="test2">
        <item name="bob" />
        <item name="joe" />
     </Collection>
     ...
</MyCustomSection>
```

I've seen a number of tutorials show how to create a Collection (like this one: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/customconfiguration/Custom_Configuration_Collections.aspx) but nothing showing how to create a collection of collections. Is this even possible?

Comment: I had asked something similar a while back.. maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126034/c-net-4-0-creating-custom-configelements-and-configcollection

Comment: You can use the same approach as described in the article and define a Item property(List<string>) in the collection element. Its all about parsing the item elements from the collection element. If you need additional help, please post your code.

Comment: The following answer might help you, except that I never got any answers at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958054/how-to-create-a-configuration-section-that-contains-a-collection-of-collections

Comment: Answered @JohnSaunders question. View the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13254002/211627